# dispatch.earliest_time in savedsearches.conf file

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

What does `dispatch.earliest_time = -15m@m` mean in savedsearches.conf file?
I'm confusing what's the exact time for **-15m@m**?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The part before the `@` is the start of the search window - 15 minutes ago, in this case.  The part after the `@` is the "snap-to" specifier.  In this case, it means round off the start time to the start of the current minute, which isn't significant because Splunk's minimum interval is 1 minute.

A better example might be `-1h@h`, which starts the search at the top of the previous hour.  It ensures the search begins with :00 even though the query may not execute until later (:05, for example).